# How many automorphisms are there for each one of the graphs A,B,C,D and E?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group, graph-isomorphism

I am currently struggling with understanding **isomorphisms** and **automorphisms**.

Can somebody in more "layman's terms" explain these terms for me and help me with this practice problem?

---

**How many automorphisms are there for each one of the graphs A,B,C,D and E?**

[image: graphs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two graphs are isomorphic if one is essentially a relabeling of the other.  That is, there is a one-to-correspondence of the vertices such that two vertices in one graph are adjacent if and only if the corresponding vertices in the other graph are adjacent.  The one-to-one correspondence itself is called an "isomorphism."

When the two graphs are the same graph, the isomorphism is called an "automorphism."  In this case, the automorphism is just a permutation of the vertices.

In example A, there are two automorphisms.  Note that an isomorphism must preserve vertex degrees.  Let $f$ be an automorphism.  Then $f(1)$ can only be $1$ or $5$.  If $f(1)=1$, then $f(2)$ must be adjacent to $f(1)$ so $f(2)=2$.  Also, $f(3)$ is adjacent to $f(2)$, so $f(3)$ is $1$ or $2$.  But $f(1)=1$ and $f$ is a permutation, so $f(3)=3$.  Continuing in this manner, we find that $f$ is the identity.

The other choice is $f(1)=5$.  Reasoning similar to the above shows that $f(2)=4, f(3)=3,f(4)=2,f(5)=1.$

The other examples are a bit more complicated than this one, but not much.

Please ask me if there is anything here you don't understand.  Try the others for yourself, and if you run into trouble, ask another question.  I think it's best if you ask about one graph at a time, showing how far you've gotten, and pinpointing your difficulty as much as possible.

Good luck.

By the way, the set of all automorphisms of a graph, together with the operation of function composition form a structure called a group, so the tag "automorphism group" that you've applied is relevant, if somewhat marginally.  On the other hand, the tag "group isomorphism" has nothing at all to do with this.  It's best not to use tags unless you're sue you know what they mean.

Comment: Would be correct to say that graph B has 10 automorphisms, C has 8 automorphisms? The graph B has 5 symmetrylines going through each of the nodes, and also it can be rotated 72 degrees 4 times before we come back to the original one. So 5+4+1 (including idx) = 10 automorphisms. Same concept for C, we have 4 symmetry lines, one vertical, one horisontal and two diagonal. We can also rotate it 3 times by 90 degrees. 4+3+1 (including idx) = 8 automorphisms. I am not sure about the details but I am trying to think how I can get the same graphs with same edgesets but with different mapping.

Comment: Or would it be correct to say that the graph B has 5! automorphisms and the graph D has 10?

Comment: B has $5!$ automorphisms and D had $10$. Every symmetry of the diagram will give you an automorphism, but it may not give you all of them.  C has $4!$ automorphisms.

Comment: Ok so. A = 2, B=5!, C=4!, D=10 and E=8? Is this correct? How can I find a graph with only one automorphism? Is the graph defined by V={0} and E={} a graph with only one automorphism, the identity? It has no symmetryline and 0 permutations. It can only map to itself.

Comment: Yes, I think all of that is right.  If this answer solved your problem, you should accept by clicking the checkmark, so it no longer shows as unsolved.

Comment: @NoName123 : For reference, a graph with only one automorphism is called an asymmetric graph (or rigid) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph